# Need help finding specific number of string in a list

Tags: python

Im trying to make a password system in python and i want to make it so that it matches the username and password based off of the number of the string in the list

this is the closest thing i can think of, but it just results in it only working if the username and the password is the same.

```
if usernames.index(usernameInput) == passwords.index(passwordInput):
    print('You are now logged into ' + usernameInput + '.')
```

Comment: Could you show more of the code before this?  What you are showing seems to match what you are describing as the desired outcome.  How is the original data being added to usernames and passwords?  One potential issue - assuming `usernames` and `passwords` are lists, you're going to throw a `ValueError` exception if either of the inputs is not found.  Instead of having two separate lists it would be better to have a list of tuples or a dictionary with key = username, value = password.  (And to actually be secure, it should be storing password hashes, not raw passwords)

Answer (score 0):

Find the index in the username list, then use that to find the matching index into the password list.

```
ix = usernames.index(usernameInput)
if passwords[ix] == passwordInput:
    print('You are now logged in')
```

Comment: Im trying to find the number in the list of the string inputted in usernameInput and passwordInput

Comment: @oodlescanoodles As far as I can see, this should do what you want.  If it doesn't, you will have to explain further, with actual examples.

Comment: im trying to do something to the effect of this but universal, just checking the position of the username in the usernames list and the password in the password lists and seeing if their position matches up.
```if usernameInput = usernames[0]: passwordInput = input('please enter your password: )
if passwordInput = passwords[0]:
print('you have logged in')
else:
print('wrong password)```
else:
print('that user does not exist')
sorry for the awful formatting, this is my first time using stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you wanted to compare the user input with the username list, then, compare the corresponding position (index) to the password list.

Firstly, assuming you have defined an aligned list of usernames and passwords:

```
# Define the list of usernames and passwords
usernames = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
passwords = ['passwordaa', 'passwordbb', 'passwordcc']
```

Upon getting user input you can compare them as so:

```
# Check if the username exists in the list
if usernameInput in usernames:
    # Get user input for the password
    passwordInput = input('Please enter your password: ')

    # Find the index of the username in the list
    userIndex = usernames.index(usernameInput)

    # Check if the password matches
    if passwordInput == passwords[userIndex]:
        print('You are now logged into ' + usernameInput + '.')
    else:
        print('Wrong password. Please try again.')
else:
    print('Invalid username. Please try again.')
```